# Upgrading facebook SDK from 2.x to 3.1

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I reopen the question. Please do not vote down unless you have a valid reason. Strange thing is somebody has similar question and was voted up.

My question:
I have a real difficulty when migrating sdk 2.x to 3.1 in iOS, no guide is dound and I searched around in the internet also no luck.
The FB SDK 2.0 is very different from 3.0 so basically i need some documentation for upgrading the fb SDK from 2.x to 3.0 for existing project. they only have guide for upgrading from 3.0 to 3.1. I tried to remove old SDK and add SDK 3.0 as per the installation instruction but everything fails

ALL i asked is a guide/tutorial to upgrade the sdk version. no documentation/discussion regarding this i can find.

Also, anyone knows when will Facebook SDK for ios be deprecated?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: **UPDATE:** Seems like facebook release a guide on this.

The link is here for those that having same issue: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.1/

Any one knows when sdk 2.0 methods will be fully removed?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently updating my app
The sdk you mentioned is great https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.1/ , it explains everything, it even explains how to transfer previous tokens to the new sdk.

I recommend looking at the upgrade tutorial to understand the new sdk and then reading the beginner tutorial, it helps understand other things.

The only flow is the open graph which is not very well described, also dialogs are still not present from the new sdk but they should be out soon
Good luck